# Django Rest Framework drop fields based on request url

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a ModelViewSet that exposes a `contacts` relation which is an extensive list of emails.

```
class EmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contacts = EmailContactSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ('id','contact_count', 'contacts')

class EmaiViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EmailSerializer
```

If I visit the url `api/emails` I get a nice list of Emails with all it's contacts. My problem is that visiting this url is slow because of all the `contacts` it needs to retrieve for every Email instance. Now I want this detailed `contact` list to be available when requesting `api/emails/<email_id>`. What can I do in DRF to drop the `contacts` field when listing Emails ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new serializer:

```
class JustEmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ('id','contact_count')
```

and override `get_serializer_class` of `EmaiViewSet` to use it only for `list` action:

```
class EmaiViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return serializers.JustEmailSerializer
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return serializers.EmailSerializer
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this??

```
class EmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Email
        # I dont see a field that shows the email field
        fields = ('id','contact_count') # you can add any other field you want 

class EmaiViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EmailSerializer
```